# error when I try to fill table with data

Tags: java, jsp

I fill table with data on `prices.jsp` page like this

```
<tbody>
<c:forEach items="${listrooms}" var="listrooms">
<tr>
    <td>${listrooms.getClassId()}</td>
    <td>${listrooms.getBeds()}</td>
    <td>${listrooms.getPrice()}</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

The data from list I get from action

```
session.setAttribute("listrooms", roomService.getRooms());
return "prices"; //redirect to page
```

`listrooms` is not null(I checked with debugger) and it contains `Room` objects which have methods `getClassId(),getBeds(),getPrice()`. But I've got an error

`The function getClassId must be used with a prefix when a default namespace is not specified`

What is wrong?

Comment: Try ${listrooms.classId}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax for accessing the properties of the bean is wrong . If your bean say `A` has a getter method like `getB()` , you can access it using [EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info) as `${A.b}` ...

Hence in your case change your code to :

```
<td>${listrooms.classId}</td>
```

where `getClassId()` shall be the public getter method of the bean `Room` .

Likewise :

```
<td>${listrooms.beds}</td>
<td>${listrooms.price}</td>
```

Comment: So every class with some fields and getters and setters for them is a bean?

Comment: Not every , refer the Java bean specs to know what qualifies as a bean . Refer to the tag wiki which I have linked !

Comment: Well my object does not implement serializable and does not have written default contstructor. However I can use it like bean?

Comment: EL uses java bean specs for accessing the public properties of a class.

Comment: So I should implement `serializable` and add default contstructor?

Comment: Not required in your case .